# How to open page existing window in testcafe

Tags: testcafe

How to open page in extisting window in testcafe or testcafestudio?

1. Run test 1
2. Click A botton
3. open page

in testcafe, step 3(open page) will open new window.
So, how can Open a page in an existing window?
Not open new window or browser.
Also need how to do this in Codeless test in testcafestudio.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [--disable-multiple-windows](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--disable-multiple-windows) flag to disable support for multiple windows. See the following topic for more information:
([https://testcafe.io/documentation/402841/guides/intermediate-guides/multiple-browser-windows?search#disable-support-for-multiple-windows)](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402841/guides/intermediate-guides/multiple-browser-windows?search#disable-support-for-multiple-windows)

Comment: then, Can i use --disable-multiple-windows flag in TestCafeStudio?